# Jmeter - Login periodically

Tags: jmeter

Previously, I execute a **setUp Thread Group** to login for each run.  The run is several hours.  But recently, the login requirement had changed.  I needed to login every half an hour.  Is there a way to make the login to "interrupt" and run every half an hour ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and use either [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) sampler to introduce 30 minutes pause.

The difference is:

- Constant Timer creates a delay before each Sampler in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- Flow Control Action sampler creates a delay exactly where it's placed

---

In general splitting login from other actions via different Thread Groups is not the best idea, you should rather be using [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) to run login just during 1st iteration or [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) if your condition is more complex.

Comment: Converting to a "normal" threadgroup with a timer, it will run independently from the application threadgroup, I figure...